# Animate calligraphy using SVG

Tags: animation, svg, css-animations, inkscape

I am trying to animate calligraphy using this method: https://css-tricks.com/animate-calligraphy-with-svg/

It's so cool that someone already got it working and shared their link on stack overflow (click the first link of the post):
[Animate calligraphy using image-file instead of SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194245/animate-calligraphy-using-image-file-instead-of-svg)

But I'm a total beginner and don't know where they got the crazy numbers for their path: "<path d="M 92.81613,118.88531.......". So far I just added some paths in the characters to make the mask paths. Can someone please explain the tutorial (first link above) for me as someone who has zero experience in working with SVG in Inkscape and animating them? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Karen, your question is a bit too unspecific to be answered here on SO. But as the author of that article I am willing to give you more help. At the bottom of the article, there is a link to my personal website. You can use the contact form there to get into a direct conversation.

Comment: Woahh this is so cool, thank you so much! I actually found a way to do it on After Effects, but thanks for reaching out anyway!

Comment: There's also an extension that does this automatically. I've not updated it for Inkscape 1.0 yet, not sure if it works or not. https://gitlab.com/Moini/ink_line_animator

Comment: @Moini I considered using those, but they don't help with paths with varying stroke-widths